# How to bypass ClassNotFound org/springframework/core/MethodInterceptor when downgraded from spring verion 4.2.6 to 4.1.9

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I am not posting any code as the issue happens when I change the version of spring from 4.2.6 to 4.1.9

So I am using Mockito to test my spring controller i.e.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

and I have the following in my set up

```
mockMvc = MOckMvcBuilders.standalonesetup(controller).build();
```

now when the version of Spring is 4.2.6 the test works completely fine but when I downgrade it to 4.1.9 (which I have to) the set up itself fails with the following error message:

```
ClassNotFound org/spring/core/MethodInterceptor
```

Now I understand that I am missing the above class which is available only in spring 4.2.x versions

But I am wondering  that how the developers used to test before spring 4.2.x versions and is there a work around I can use to get the test running.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: You didn't downgrade *completely*; you're still including some library somewhere that requires 4.2. Posting the complete stack trace would be a first step.

Comment: Ok I will post the complete stack trace soon. I currently do not have access to the machine that has the code.

Comment: @chrylis You were actually absolutely right, there were dependency conflicts, had two libs doing the same thing. I cannot express how grateful I am. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Conditional of spring 4 specifically @ConditionalOnClass on your test @Configuration class.

Comment: @BaseemRedaZohdy Could you please elaborate or point me to an example. I would really appreciate that. Thanks.